# Group document mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to group document with mongodb but couldn't figure out how.

I have a document looks like this

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('12345'),
    username: 'asd',
    region: 'zxc',
    amount: 500,
    type: 'car',
    brand: 'vent',
    order: 2
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('98283'),
    username: 'asd',
    region: 'zxc',
    amount: 1500,
    type: 'car',
    brand: 'dinosaur',
    order: 1
}
```

And I want to group the document by username, region, type and make a new sub document from the result and order the sub-document ascending by the order. Also calculate the amount as a totalAmount. Which looks like this.

```
{
    username: 'asd',
    region: 'zxc',
    type: 'car',
    cart: [
        {
            brand: 'dinosaur',
            amount: 1500
        },
        {
            brand: 'vent',
            amount: 500
        }
    ],
    totalAmount: 2000
}
```

I could only do this so far

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {username: "$username"},
            region: {$first: "$region"},
            type: {$first: "$type"},
            totalAmount: {$sum: "$amount"}
        }
    }
])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put all of the fields you want to group on in the `_id`.

Use $push to collect values into an array, and $sum to compute the total:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        username: "$username",
        region: "$region",
        type: "$type"
      },
      cart: {
        $push: {
          brand: "$brand",
          amount: "$amount"
        }
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lRQQ9CmHQf9)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you please help me with the order of the sub document? It supposed to be dinosaur first then vent as the dinosaur order is 1 and vent is 2. I tried this but no luck ```db.collection.aggregate([{...group}, {  $sort: { order: 1 } }])```

Comment: $sort by order before grouping